# Successions and series, exercise.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

It is true that

if $\;a_n>0\;$ and $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n + 1}}{ a_n}<1\;,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;?$

Is that true or false?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried a few examples?

Comment: Let $\ell=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$, $a_{n+1}\leqslant (\ell+\varepsilon)a_n$ for $n$ large enough, take $\varepsilon$ small enough so that $\ell+\varepsilon<1$, you'll then be able to conclude by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true.

Since $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<1\;,\;$ there exist $\;h\in\left]0,1\right[\;$ and $\;\nu\in\mathbb{N}\;$ such that

$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<h\quad$ for all $\;n>\nu\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Since $\;a_n>0\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ from $(*)$ we get that

$0<a_{n+1}<h^{n-\nu}a_{\nu+1}\;$ for all $\;n>\nu\;.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

Moreover, $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}h^{n-\nu}a_{\nu+1}=0\;$ and, by applying the squeeze theorem to the inequalities $(**)$, we get that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=0\;,\;$ hence

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$

---

Another way to prove that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$

From $(*)$ it follows that

$a_{n+1}<a_n\quad$ for all $\;n>\nu\;.$

Consequently, there exists $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf\limits_{n>\nu}\;\{a_n\}=l\ge0\;.$

If $\;l>0\;,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\dfrac{l}{l}=1\;,\;$ but it is impossible because, for hypothesis, $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<1\;.$

Consequently, it results that $\;l=0\;$ that is

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\;.$